# Phalcon Tools model create alias is duplicated for FK to same table

Tags: phalcon, scaffolding

I am trying to scaffold a model using Phalcon Tools. Problem is that I have various FK's that reference the same table, for instance: user_created and user_modified in User table.

The model then aliases them both as follows:

```
$this->hasMany('id', 'PhalconRest\Models\User', 'created_by', ['alias' => 'User']);
$this->hasMany('id', 'PhalconRest\Models\User', 'modified_by', ['alias' => 'User']);
```

Is there a way to override this behaviour? I cannot seem to find a switch for that.

Comment: Could you please open an issue with script to reproducse at https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the Alias
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.1/db-models-relationships#aliases

```
$this->hasMany('id', 'PhalconRest\Models\User', 'created_by', ['alias' => 'User1']);
$this->hasMany('id', 'PhalconRest\Models\User', 'modified_by', ['alias' => 'User2']);
```

Comment: Which is what I eventually did but it defeats the purpose of scaffolding